# Perl WWW Mechanize submit_form() not pointing to form_number requested How to fix?

Tags: html, forms, perl, mechanize

Let's use this webpage for this problem as I will post the Perl snippet and the error/information message reported.  At [finance.yahoo.com](http://finance.yahoo.com) enter your favorite ticker (I used GEOR).  Hit go, then on left panel select Historic Prices.  The bottom form is the one of interest for this problem.

There appears to be two forms on this page with submit, the second one is the one I want to activate and submit with names/values.  When executing my Perl code, it seems to be stuck on the first one regardless of what I set `form_number => xx` to.  I want the 2nd one which should return a table of historic prices pertaining to the programmed values I submitted via `with_fields` args, but instead tries to submit to the ticker form and not the historic prices form.  Code here:

```
$mech -> follow_link (text => "Historical Prices");
print "-D-: Submits: ",$mech->find_all_submits();
$mech->submit_form(
    form_number => 1,
    with_fields => {s => "GEOR",
                    a => "11",
                    b => "20",
                    c => "2013",
                    d => "11",
                    e => "31",
                    f => "2013",
                    g => "d",
                   }
);
my $PageContent = $mech -> content ();
&Dumper($PageContent, "Dump_Historic.txt");
exit;
```

I've tied the values for form_number as 0, 1, 2. and 3 and I still get the following message in the command window:

There are 2 forms with the named fields, the first one was used at: "Path" line 41. This line is the submit_form line above.

I've confirmed that webpage contained the historic prices form as I dumped the content after doing the follow link cmd above,  It's messy but may be easier for you to view source of page yourself than me copying the contents here.  You'll see two nameless submit buttons text field "GO" and the intend one "Get Prices".

So how do I get this to successfully submit the form containing the "Get Prices" ostensibly the 2nd form?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow.  Did you forget to include your console output?  It says that you got a message from the console, but you didn't include what it is.

Comment: Hi, thank your for the warm reception.  Actually the console messge is there, U should have "" it.  Here is the console message:

Comment: Console message: "There are 2 forms with the named fields, the first one was used at: "Path" line 41."  Rhw "Path" is the path and perl file I am working on.

Answer (score 0):

You can get same result with **only one** GET request:

```
$mech->get("http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=GEOR&a=04&b=22&c=2009&d=08&e=30&f=2013&g=w");
```

Comment: Actually I am doing other stuff on the page datamining.  The problem isn't how to concise the code.  The problem is getting it to submit to correct from and get contents back that contain a table in this case akk stock prices for GEOR from Dec 15, 2012 to Dec 31, 2012.   Since the code won't submit to form_number 2, I get contents results from a confused form 1's results..

Comment: On the second thought, this seems like a work around the mechanize bug... I would at least be enabmed on this case, but concern is a number of different kind of pages with more than one submittable form would have the same kind of issue... So is it possible making the submit work?  Thanks a bunch on the one line answer.  I realized if I parameterize it, it will work for historic prices...